# No output being printed

Tags: python, data-structures, printing, linked-list, insert

no output printed can you please spot errors in these code??I tried to create linked list and insert and print the data but its not showing me in the output

```
class node:
  def __init__(self,data):
      self.data=data
      self.next=None;
class linkedlist:
  def __init__(self):
      self.start=None;`
  def insertfirst(self,value):
      newnode=node(value)
      if(self.start==None):
          self.start=newnode;
      else:
          temp=self.start
          self.start=newnode
          newnode.next=temp;
  def viewlist(self):
      if(self.start==None):
          print("list is empty");
      else:
          temp=self.start
          while(temp.next!=None):
              print(temp.data,end='')
              temp=temp.next;
myfll=linkedlist()
myfll.insertfirst(9)
myfll.insertfirst(10)
myfll.insertfirst(11)
myfll.viewlist
```

Comment: you are missing parenthesis in last line

Comment: @usman please consider using debugger, before straight jumping to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program with minimum modifications.

```py
class node:
  def __init__(self,data):
      self.data=data
      self.next=None
class linkedlist:
  def __init__(self):
      self.start=None
  def insertfirst(self,value):
      newnode=node(value)
      if(self.start==None):
          self.start=newnode
      else:
          temp=self.start
          self.start=newnode
          newnode.next=temp
  def viewlist(self):
      if(self.start==None):
          print("list is empty")
      else:
          temp=self.start
          while(temp!=None):
              print(temp.data,end=' ')
              temp=temp.next
myfll=linkedlist()
myfll.insertfirst(9)
myfll.insertfirst(10)
myfll.insertfirst(11)
myfll.viewlist()
```

Output

```
11 10 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a parentheses missing in the last line -

```
myfll.viewlist ()
```

Just as you called constructors for `linkedlist()` using brackets after them, in the same way `viewlist` must be called using brackets after them because they are **methods ( function of a class)** and need to be invoked using brackets.

Hope this help !